# Java: Get time in "hh:MM:ss a" format

Tags: java, android, date, android-studio

I was building an android app and i was using `Date` class in my project to get the current date. I formatted the date with `simpledateformatter` and displayed it like `dd-mm-yyyy` (i.e. day month year) .

Now i also want to get the time in format of `hh:MM:ss a` (hours minutes seconds AM/PM)

As i was using date's instance i saw that it displays date and time also ( in default format). So i tried to fetch time from the date's instance.(let's say d is date class instance). I also found `getTime()` method of date class and performed `d.getTime()` but it returned me a long (which is duration from some fixed time from past to current time). Now i want time in desired format but this `getTime()` method is giving me long.

May you provide me some way on how to process this long value to get the desired format of time out of it. For example , `d.getTime()` return me some value( say 11233) and i want in format like this (11:33:22).

Comment: paste some code

Comment: If you're starting to use Date, better to use [JSR-310 backport for Android](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) instead of Date.

Comment: Don't use `Date` and `SimpleDateFormat` since they are old and poorly designed. Use java.time, the modern Java date and time API. If not yet on API level 26, then through the backport as @ישואוהבאותך mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

You can make that

```
private final String DATE_FORMAT = "dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss";
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT);
Date got = sdf.parse(date);
```

It returns Date with time to you

Comment: But i want to extract time out of it and not the date , then should i do?

Comment: Although i can make it string and can extract time out of it. But , will it be a good Decision to extract it like that?

Comment: @ArjunSharma Do you need `Time` or `String`? Or which Type of your time do you want to get?

Comment: I am sorry i am little bit confused! I want to know a thing first, i have a button which displays the time in it.  And when i press that button then it shows timepicker dialog and displays the time which was previously set. And now if some change time i would like to store it and display it on the time button. Which type i should use for the time?

Answer (score 2):

Use this snippet to get the `date` and `time` both.

```
public String currentDateTime() {
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    SimpleDateFormat dateformat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm:ss aa");  //it will give you the date in the formate that is given in the image
    String datetime = dateformat.format(c.getTime()); // it will give you the date
    return datetime;
}
```

**Note:** Take a look in the image [image].

Comment: And if i need only time out of it then i can make it a string then extract the time as a substring out of it , right?

Answer (score 1):

Date().getTime() is providing you the timestamp

Change the format to your requirement like `mm:hh:ss a`

Kotlin

```
fun getDateTime():String {
    val inputFormat = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'", Locale.getDefault())
    val date = Date()
    return inputFormat.format(date.time)
}
```

JAVA

```
private String getDateTime(){
        SimpleDateFormat format=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'", Locale.getDefault());
        return format.format(new Date().getTime());
    }
```